# Help Proving Quotient of Sequences Is Finite

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I'm trying prove that $\displaystyle \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is finite, when I know that $\displaystyle \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}≤\frac{b_{n+2}}{b_n}$.

I'm a little stuck, but have some inclination to think that it has something to do with manipulating $\displaystyle \frac{a_n}{b_n}≤\frac{a_{n-2}}{b_{n-2}}\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n-1}}$, which follows from the above inequality.

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
Assume $a_n$ and $b_n$ are positive sequences.

Comment: This is false. Is it a typo and it should be what I said below? Or did you think it could be true like that?

Comment: $b_n=1$ and $a_n=(-2)^n$ gives a counter-example too..

Comment: It was not a typo. But, I initially had assumed that $a_n$ and $b_n$ were positive series, and thought it would be inconsequential. With that assumption, is it still possible to construct a counter argument? So far, I haven't been able to come up with one.

Answer (score 1):

This is false as stated. Take $a_n=n^3$ and $b_n=n^2$. Then $\limsup \frac{a_n}{b_n}=+\infty$ and yet
$$
\frac{b_{n+2}}{b_n}-\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^2-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^3=\frac{1}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\geq\frac{1}{n}\geq 0\qquad\forall n\geq 1.
$$

If you replace your condition by
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}\leq \frac{a_n}{b_n}
$$
then the sequence is nonincreasing. So 
$$-\infty\leq \lim \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \limsup \frac{a_n}{b_n}\leq \frac{a_1}{b_1}<\infty.
$$

Comment: In the second version , it could be -$\infty$ ,too.Maybe the condition could be $ a_{n+2}/a_n \leq b_{n+1}/b_n$

Comment: @HalilDuru If you notice, I wrote $-\infty \leq \lim$ not $<$.

Comment: i saw -- just saying the original problem couldn't be with that second condition too..